# Cannot connect to R kernal on Google Cloud Platform JupyterLab notebook

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, kernel, jupyter-lab

I created a new instance with an R environment, but when trying to start a notebook with an R kernel, it never connects. Python kernels work fine.

I followed the advice on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69314774/cannot-connect-to-r-kernel-using-jupyter-notebook-instance-on-google-ai-platform/69315764#69315764) post, but when I tried to run the update.packages line as suggested in it, it failed unless I installed them in a personal library. I went through all the updates but in the end it still wasn't connecting to the kernel.

This is the error I get that requires me to write on the personal library:

> Warning in install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l,
> contriburl = contriburl,  :   'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"'
> is not writable

After installing on a personal library, I restarted the instance, and the kernel does not connect. I still see the same error:

> Error: package ‘IRkernel’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please
> re-install it

So looks like the installation did not work. Any advice on how to resolve it?